How can I authenticate using the token exchange grant type for impersonation with spring boot and keycloak?
To put a bit of context: I have successfully been able to do this using curl so yes, I probably can come up with a home made solution that works but the point of my question here it to not have to maintain auth-related classes and rather leverage what spring boot has to give.
What I'm trying to do is Impersonation through token exchange. To ease things up I'm considering Direct Naked Impersonation
I have a private service (let's call it S) triggered by an event (in an event sourced environment). The event carries an original JWT that comes from the original user. As there is no guarantee in terms of time-to-process we can consider that this JWT has expired.
S is working as an anti corruption layer and is interacting with a legacy public GraphQL API (let's call it A).
To do so, S needs to be authenticated as a user being authorised to access the specific entities it's going to work with in A.
Until now S only had to interact on behalf of a single user and so this was working fine:
@Bean
fun legacyServerGraphQLClient(
    legacyServerProperties: LegacyServerProperties,
    clientRegistrationRepository: InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
    clientService: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService
): WebClientGraphQLClient = MonoGraphQLClient.createWithWebClient(WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(legacyServerProperties.httpUrl)
    .filter(
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository,
                clientService
            )
        ).also {
            // We know we use only one provider, so it's easier and less coupled to the actual value to do things like this
            it.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationRepository.first().registrationId)
        }
    )
    .build()

The app config looking like this:
spring:
  security.oauth2.client:
    registration:
      keycloak:
        client-id: '${SPRING_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID:service-s}'
        client-secret: '${SPRING_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}'
        authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
    provider:
      keycloak:
        issuer-uri: '${SPRING_OAUTH_ISSUER_URI}'

So now: how can I adapt this to work with TOKEN EXCHANGE for a specific audience and a specific requested_subject ?
I tried going down this road while changing the authorization-grant-type to urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange:
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrationRepository,
        clientService
    ).apply {
        setAuthorizedClientProvider(TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider().apply {
            setAccessTokenResponseClient(WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient().apply {
                addParametersConverter {
                    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>().apply {
                        add("audience", "legacy-api-A")
                        add("requested_subject", "myspecificuser")
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
)

This fails because I have no subject_token at this point in the code:

At this point thoughts are as such: Spring just doesn't support Direct Naked Impersonation which I guess there are multiple good reasons why.
So then I'm thinking I could just chain my client_credentials auth, use the provided token as the subject_token and voilà! token_exchange here you come! But then I hit this issue where I have no idea how to chain these two. I tried something like:
@Bean
fun legacyServerGraphQLClient(
    legacyServerProperties: LegacyServerProperties,
    clientRegistrationRepository: InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
    clientService: ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService
): WebClientGraphQLClient = MonoGraphQLClient.createWithWebClient(WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(legacyServerProperties.httpUrl)
    .filter(
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository,
                clientService
            )
        ).also {
            // We know we use only one provider, so it's easier and less coupled to the actual value to do things like this
            it.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("reg-cc")
        }
    )
    .filter(
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository,
                clientService
            ).apply {
                setAuthorizedClientProvider(TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider().apply {
                    setAccessTokenResponseClient(WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient().apply {
                        addParametersConverter {
                            LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>().apply {
                                add("audience", "legacy-api-A")
                                add("requested_subject", "myspecificuser")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        ).also {
            // We know we use only one provider, so it's easier and less coupled to the actual value to do things like this
            it.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("reg-te")
        }
    )
    build()

But the second filter doesn't pick up the authorization header from the first one so again: no subject token.
Before going further I'd be happy if anyone could give me pointers cause I' don't really like my next solutions which are:

Rewrite a TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider to allow for Direct Naked Impersonation
Add a custom filter that just does an http request to the token endpoint

I'm pretty sure it is possible to do token exchange as the code is there but I feel like i'm just not using it in the nominal case and as such I can't find how to chain things right.
As a final note please understand that everything I'm trying to do programatically has already been tested through curl requests. So, from a Keycloak point of view everything works. I just need to get the code going.
I'm using Java 21, spring boot 3.3.0 and Keycloak 24.0.5.
Thank you

What is sending the request to S? How is this request authorized? How is the user you want to "impersonate" involved?

I edited the explanations around S. As a quick reference: S is triggered by an event that contains a JWT that we can consider as expired but carries the identity of the user to impersonate. Originally that user was authenticated through a classic frontend client and the server ensured it had the proper authorisations after which it forwarded the command to our event sourced application.

You are correct that the default support for Token Exchange does not intend Direct Naked Impersonation, which as far as I can tell is largely a keycloak concept (that I wouldn't recommend).
However, the support is flexible and most everything can be customized. The TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider allows for customizing the subjectTokenResolver, which is a Function<OAuth2AuthorizationContext, Mono<OAuth2Token>> (see docs). Additionally, you can customize the parameters of the token request.
You can provide your own implementation of OAuth2Token to assist with adding the requested_subject parameter like this:
@Configuration
public class TokenExchangeConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider tokenExchange(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        var authorizedClientManager = createAuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

        var authorizedClientProvider = new TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
        var subjectTokenResolver = createSubjectTokenResolver(authorizedClientManager, "keycloak");
        authorizedClientProvider.setSubjectTokenResolver(subjectTokenResolver);

        var tokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient();
        tokenResponseClient.addParametersConverter(subjectParametersConverter());
        authorizedClientProvider.setAccessTokenResponseClient(tokenResponseClient)

        return authorizedClientProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Create a standalone {@link ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager} for resolving
     * the subject token using {@code client_credentials}.
     */
    private static ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager createAuthorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        var authorizedClientProvider =
            ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        var authorizedClientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    /**
     * Create a {@code Function} to resolve a token from the current principal.
     */
    private static Function<OAuth2AuthorizationContext, Mono<OAuth2Token>> createSubjectTokenResolver(
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager, String clientRegistrationId) {

        var anonymousUser = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("anonymous", "anonymousUser",
            AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));

        return (context) -> {
            var authorizeRequest =
                OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
                    .principal(anonymousUser)
                    .build();

            return authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
                .map(OAuth2AuthorizedClient::getAccessToken)
                .map((accessToken) -> new DirectImpersonationOAuth2Token(context.getPrincipal(), accessToken));
        };
    }

    private static Converter<TokenExchangeGrantRequest, MultiValueMap<String, String>> subjectParametersConverter() {
        return (grantRequest) -> {
            var subjectToken = (DirectImpersonationOAuth2Token) grantRequest.getSubjectToken();
            var parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
            parameters.set("audience", "legacy-api-A");
            parameters.set("requested_subject", subjectToken.getRequestedSubject().getName());
            return parameters;
        };
    }

    private static class DirectImpersonationOAuth2Token extends AbstractOAuth2Token {

        private final Authentication requestedSubject;

        protected DirectImpersonationOAuth2Token(Authentication requestedSubject, OAuth2Token accessToken) {
            super(accessToken.getTokenValue(), accessToken.getIssuedAt(), accessToken.getExpiresAt());
            this.requestedSubject = requestedSubject;
        }

        public Authentication getRequestedSubject() {
            return this.requestedSubject;
        }
    }

}

If you need to use AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead of DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager you won't use this bean-based config (again see docs), but you should be able to adapt it easily.

Thanks for the pointers. I will try to see what I can do here. I'm not a huge fan of DNI either and I'm trying to avoid. I'm mostly trying to chain 2 authentifications: 1/ A client credentials grant (cached and refreshed as needed) followed by 2/ A token exchange grant depending on the user I need to impersonate on a per request basis.

I tried returning null as the token value, it passes Spring but the request still contains the subject_token key even though it's empty and that gives me an invalid token error from Keycloak.

I see. I’m not at my desk right now to update the answer but you can customize the request parameters of the token request as well, so you should be able to get rid of the parameter. But I wonder why you aren’t just putting the user’s token in the subject token and possibly the client credentials token in the actor token? That seems like what you should be doing.

The reason I'm not doing this is that the user's token will be expired so my understanding is that this will just fail (mind you, haven't tested this because that's how I understood it)

Moreover it seems Keycloak doesn't support the actor token ? Can't find anything in their docs about it

"The reason I'm not doing this is that the user's token will be expired" - This is a fairly concerning requirement, and I would encourage you to push for a solution that doesn't involve using expired tokens. Regardless, I've updated the code example in the answer based on your feedback, and it now includes customization of the parameters.

Thanks for your addition. Just to answer your concern regarding the expired tokens, I am not using them in this part of the app. They are just a way to extract the user identity. Not to provide authorisation for the following steps. They signify that the user was authorised to send the original command to the S stack. But then S should authentify and get the authorisation for its requests to A on behalf of the original user (what I'm tryin to achieve here). I hope this helps you understand why we're doing it like this.

i do have an issue with everything being declared in Beans though which is that the user's identity should be provided at the request time . I need to see how I'm going to make sure I don not re-authenticate on each request and make sure multiple tokens can live in parallel as S may be processing events from different users in parallel.

Also going further in trying to implement your solution I'm facing the fact that I'm using a reactive approach and ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider implementations doesn't seem to provide as much flexibility. I can't remove the SUBJECT_TOKEN fields.

Oh I apologize. I missed that you are using reactive. Let me provide an update.

Unfortunately, it's a bit more involved for reactive and since we can't remove parameters, we need to provide a dummy subject_token via the subjectTokenResolver. I've updated the code example to do this. Note that the authorization manager within an authorization manager example is taken from this sample in Spring Authorization Server.

Thanks for the update. I feel like there might be an issue though with the fact that the authorizedClientService is going to be shared between the top level authorization manager and the one in your code leading to authentication happening once because they would both use the same clientRegistrationId and principalName thus having the second call use the result from the first one. I guess changing anonymousUser to something else would make this work. Or maybe I'm missing something ?

FYI I put a followup question here about how I could handle authentication to various requested_subject in case you're interested using the solution I currently have for the current question.

I accepted this answer although I'm still using my own solution because I feel like this is how things should be done. I'm only doing it my own way because it does the same thing with one less request to the SSO and that I don't intend on reusing this in the future. For anything long terms one should use Steve's solution.

In addition to being tied to a Keycloak proprietary extension (as pointed out by @steve-riesenberg already), this seems over-complicated and inefficient (if I understand well, a user having actions that would trigger let's say 10 requests in a few seconds, would require the authorization server to issue 11 tokens:

1 access token for the OAuth2 client (frontend or BFF) to query the resource server
for each request, 1 new token for the resource server to query the legacy GraphQL API

Moreover, the reason for this solution ("As there is no guarantee in terms of time-to-process we can consider that this JWT has expired") is most probably wrong:

most OAuth2 clients refresh access token way before it expire. For instance, the default Spring Security OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager refreshes not only expired tokens but also those expiring within the next 60s. Any serious OAuth2 client library does about the same.
there should be a "grace" period for access tokens validation. I can't remember where I read it, but I think it is specified somewhere that resource servers should accept token expired less than 2 seconds ago, or so. If I remember well, motivation was possible network latencies and small shift between servers clocks in the case of JWT access tokens.

Long story short, unless there is a good reason for a huge delay (more than a minute) between the instant when the OAuth2 client sends the request to the resource server (S in the question) and the instant when the legacy GraphQL API (A in the question) receives the request from the resource server, the most efficient and simple solution by far is for S to read the access token from the security context and forward it to A.

Thanks for your answer. The thing is there is no security context at that point because I just have a token as metadata of an event that may have happened generally a few seconds ago, issued by another service. In some case it could already be expired. Then the actions that S is going to take are by the hundreds towards A because I'm automating heavy tasks that are described in a CSV. So the process takes more or less an hour during which it's going to need to be authenticated. I agree it's inefficient but other solutions require heavy modifications to A that cost even more.

So, it takes more than an hour for S to forward a user request to A. I'm happy not to be the one in charge of user satisfaction... Have you considered adding an endpoint on A, reserved to S, and which would expect the user ID as request parameter or path variable instead of extracting it from the token claims?

As I explained, S is going to make hundreds of calls to A. The users are actually pretty satisfied because it took them 2 days work to do that by hand before this service was made available. See it as an automation. That's not the point anyways.
And yes, having A evolve was obviously on top of our mind but we still need to maintain security on the API and we can't give a user the rights to freely do whatever it wants on whatever user just based on a user id that would be provided as a parameter.

You did not get my point. S gets the user ID from the token and gives it to A as a parameter on a dedicated endpoint that only S is allowed to call. S would use client credentials to get a token and be authorized as itself (not on behalf of the user).

Sorry, I indeed didn't get your point. We thought about doing something like this or event putting up another instance of A that would be private and a more lenient in terms of authz but this is taking quite some risks. A is a big ball of mud so our first choice was to try and impersonate a user to make sure we don't break anything in A. Eventually we will completely bypass A (we're also actively working on that). Here we want a solution to quickly make this tool available and help the team's productivity. Token Exchange and Impersonation seemed the perfect fit.

So, I ended up making it possible to do DNI which in terms of code only required me to override one interface implementation and trick the ClientManager into thinking the subject token was there. It's not the best solution but it works.
Hopefully someone will at some point be able to tell me how I can easily chain two authentications using the spring filter functions (client credentials followed by token exchange using the CC as the subject_token)
Right now here is what it looks like:
My new class
package mypackage

import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.http.ReactiveHttpInputMessage
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.TokenExchangeGrantRequest
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2Token
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2ParameterNames
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.web.reactive.function.OAuth2BodyExtractors
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractor
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.FormInserter
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

/**
 * @see org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient
 */
class WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient() :
    ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<TokenExchangeGrantRequest> {
    private val webClient: WebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeaders {
            it.accept = listOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            it.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED
        }
        .build()

    private val bodyExtractor: BodyExtractor<Mono<OAuth2AccessTokenResponse>, ReactiveHttpInputMessage> =
        OAuth2BodyExtractors.oauth2AccessTokenResponse()

    var parametersProvider: () -> MultiValueMap<String, String> = { LinkedMultiValueMap() }

    override fun getTokenResponse(grantRequest: TokenExchangeGrantRequest): Mono<OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> =
        Mono.defer {
            this.webClient.post()
                .uri(grantRequest.clientRegistration.providerDetails.tokenUri)
                .body(createTokenRequestBody(grantRequest))
                .exchangeToMono { it.body(this.bodyExtractor) }
        }

    private fun createTokenRequestBody(grantRequest: TokenExchangeGrantRequest): FormInserter<String> = BodyInserters
        .fromFormData(parametersProvider.invoke())
        .apply {
            with(OAuth2ParameterNames.GRANT_TYPE, grantRequest.grantType.value)

            val clientRegistration = grantRequest.clientRegistration
            with(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ID, clientRegistration.clientId)
            with(OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_SECRET, clientRegistration.clientSecret)
            with(OAuth2ParameterNames.REQUESTED_TOKEN_TYPE, ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_VALUE)

            grantRequest.subjectToken?.takeIf { it.tokenValue != null }?.let {
                with(OAuth2ParameterNames.SUBJECT_TOKEN, it.tokenValue)
                with(OAuth2ParameterNames.SUBJECT_TOKEN_TYPE, tokenType(it))
            }

            grantRequest.actorToken?.takeIf { it.tokenValue != null }?.let {
                with(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACTOR_TOKEN, it.tokenValue)
                with(OAuth2ParameterNames.ACTOR_TOKEN_TYPE, tokenType(it))
            }

            grantRequest.clientRegistration.scopes?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let {
                with(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE, it.joinToString(" "))
            }
        }

    companion object {
        private const val ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_VALUE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token"
        private const val JWT_TOKEN_TYPE_VALUE = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt"

        private fun tokenType(token: OAuth2Token): String =
            if (token is Jwt) JWT_TOKEN_TYPE_VALUE else ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_VALUE
    }
}

How I configured my filter function
ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        clientRegistrationRepository,
        clientService
    ).apply {
        setAuthorizedClientProvider(TokenExchangeReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider().apply {
            // Bypassing Spring checks
            setSubjectTokenResolver { Mono.just(OAuth2Token { null }) }
            // Overriding client with our more permissive one
            setAccessTokenResponseClient(WebClientReactiveTokenExchangeTokenResponseClient().apply {
                parametersProvider = {
                    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>().apply {
                        add("audience", "legacy-api-A")
                        add("requested_subject", "myspecificuser")
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
).also {
    // We know we use only one provider, so it's easier and less coupled to the actual value to do things like this
    it.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationRepository.first().registrationId)
}

I will be providing the parameters through configuration.

Just to clarify, you wouldn't want to use client_credentials tokens as the subject_token as you are impersonating an end-user or resource owner, so that is who the "subject" is. See my updated answer to hopefully provide a solution that doesn't require the extra code duplication.

Maybe there's something about how Keycloak does this ? The way I've been able to make impersonation work is by providing a subject_token which is a valid token of someone wanting to to the action then using requested_subject to specify which user I want to impersonate. Obviously this required configuration and permissions given to the client in the KC admin interface.
I think the issue with Keycloak may lie in the fact they have a not-so-standard approach to token exchange. For example, I can't declare an actor_token.

Right. I believe even their docs state that token exchange support is not implemented to spec. Unfortunately, the token exchange spec does not have very many use cases covered, so it leaves a little to be desired. But I don't really know what the inspiration is for Keycloak's apparently non-standard implementation.
